# Using Offset function in Azure Data Factory Data Flow

Tags: azure-data-factory, offset

I have figured out how to use the 'offset' function on a Copy Data activity in ADF, however, I was wondering is there a similar way to do that with a Data Flow. How do I offset a range of outputs using Pagination rules?

Tried sticking 'offset={offset}' into the relative URL of the data flow however, {} is an illegal char.

Job failed due to reason: at Source 'srcIICSrest': Illegal character in query at index 42: /saas//api/v2/activity/activityLog?offset={offset}

Answer (score 0):

Pagination rules for copy activity and dataflow activity are different. Check the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#example-1-variables-in-queryparameters) for details. I reproduced the same steps and got the error.
[image]

The fallback approach is executing the dataflow for all the values of offset. Below is the detailed approach to do the same.

- Take `ForEach` activity to iterate over a range of values for offset.
  [image]
- Then **Dataflow activity** is taken in the for-each activity. For each value of offset, it executes a Data Flow activity. The Data Flow activity is configured to pass the offset value to the source dataset of the Data Flow.

[image]

- The source dataset of the Data Flow has a parameter named "Offset" that is used to specify the offset value.

[image]

By this way, you can do pagination in dataflow.